# phpunit xml sequential testing issue

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I'm Having an issue when running a testsuite, I need to run OperatorUserTest.php first to setup the users permissions, Im hoping I can do something like this

```
 <testsuite name="Operator Test Suite">
        <file>./tests/Users/OperatorUserTest.php</file>
        <directory>./tests/Projects</directory>
        <directory>./tests/Operators/UnitTesting</directory>

    </testsuite>
```

but the above errors as for some reason the file does not fully run and the operators/UnitTesting directory is called before it finishes. The code below works fine.

```
  <testsuite name="Operator Test Suite">
        <directory>./tests/Users</directory>
        <exclude>
            <file>./tests/Users/UserTest.php</file>
        </exclude>
        <directory>./tests/Projects</directory>
        <directory>./tests/Operators/UnitTesting</directory>

    </testsuite>
```

Am I doing something wrong with using the file first? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming these permissions are stored in a database, is this correct?

If you need to perform a task before each test, i.e. populate user's permissions in a database table, you should use the `setup()` method which runs before every test.

Laravel provides some helpers for this, as well. The `RefreshDatabase` trait will run migrations and rollbacks before and after tests, respectively.

Then you can assert the permissions are available using `assertDatabaseHas`.

Comment: Hey, yea the users permissions are stored in the database.

I have 6 tests and I was hoping rather then setting the user permissions each time I could run OperatorUserTest.php first and then the tests, so if user permissions are changed it can be changed in one place.

It works when using the directory and excluding the others from the example above but when I try only call the file it does not, any ideas to what the cause of this could be?

Comment: So you want the permissions from OperatorUserTest to be used in the following 6 tests?

Comment: Yep the same permissions

Comment: So you can certainly do that, however it goes against one of the fundamentals of unit testing which atomicity between tests. Essentially each test should start from a clean slate, not using data or state from previous tests. I'd recommend recreating the permissions before every test for that reason

Comment: Ah it is essentially one test but there was a lot of routes to test so we split them up for readability.

Do you know why if the file is called the directories are called before it finishes? 

If we call the directory with OperaorUserTest and exclude the other files it works fine, can't find a reason for this.

Thanks

Comment: Not off the top of my head, sorry. It's not reading them in alphabetically is it?

Comment: No worries, I don't believe so. If i call the files separately it works

    <file>./tests/Users/OperatorUserTest.php</file>
    <file>./tests/Operators/UnitTesting/FacilityTest.php</file>

just when I call the directory for some reason it runs before OperatorUserTest finished. Can't find the reason for it